# Making a BASIC angularjs app isn't working for me and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

Here are my files: 
timeline.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="timelineApp"> 

    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <p>{{ title }}</p>
    </div>



    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var timelineApp = angular.module("timelineApp", []);
```

MainController.js:

```
timelineApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
      $scope.title = 'this is a test'; 
    }]);
```

What am I missing? I thought I did everything right but for some reason it won't even display the title.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server? If you are doing it locally you need to add the actual protocol to the angularjs library url (ie add the http:// part)

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: does the script tag work with `src="//...."` don't you need a http: before those // ?

Comment: @Lusk116, leaving off the protocol makes the browser use whatever protocol the current page is on, for instance if you are on a page using https:// the browsers prepends https: to the src url

Comment: this fiddle does exactly the same [https://jsfiddle.net/bbtjv2vd/](https://jsfiddle.net/bbtjv2vd/) and is working, dont forget to set the javascript load type to "No wrap - in <body>". maybe your file structure isn't right ?

Comment: Did you take a look into development tools in your browser?  Do you get some errors? What is about network log?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think that's my problem. I'm running locally. How do I add the protocol to the angularjs library url?

Comment: Just add http: to the front of the src attribute on your script that includes it, ie `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/` should be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/` Without specifying the protocol, the browser will append `file:///` when running locally and since you do not have a local path of `ajax.googleapis....` etc it doesnt find the script

Comment: @PatrickEvans I did that and it still only outputs {{title}}. Is there anything else im missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the console to see if you are getting errors?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I haven't, I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: On most browsers just hit F12 and then click console tab and if there are errors it will list them there.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Cool, yes there were four errors:

Comment: http://localhost:8080/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/MainController.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/timelineInfo.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:4042 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=timelineApp&p1=Erro…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A339)

Comment: I'm sorry @PatrickEvans , i tried to format them and they accidentally sent as a text blob

Comment: @PatrickEvans I GOT IT! Thank you so much! But what I did to fix it was that I created a angular.min.js file in the same folder as my index. I still got the errors of the 404 so I moved all my js files up into the index folder too. Why does this work? The src points to a "js/..." but even though it points there it grabs the file in my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to initialize your angular module simply using

```
angular.module("myApp")
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/frishi/8Lgytjaj/

This worked for me:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('timelineApp', [])
    .controller("MainController", MainController);
})();

function MainController($scope){
    $scope.title = "Foo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`timelineApp` should be in global scope like `angular` is, but try

```
angular
   .module('timelineApp')
   .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
      $scope.title = 'this is a test'; 
    }]);
```

in MainController.js

to create a module use `angular.module('app', []);` don't forget the brackets `[]`, you can add other modules like thirdparty modules here like `angular.module('app',['superModule', 'ui-router']`

if you want to use your module and register new controllers or directives, retrieve it with

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller(....
app.directive(....
```

now without the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

In maincontroller

var timelineApp=angular.module("timelineApp", []);

timelineApp.controller('MainController',  function($scope) { $scope.title = 'this is a test';
 });